# Bevel works on one side but not the other

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a curved indent. I did one side, but when I try to select and bevel the other side, it doesn't bevel.

Selected edge
[image: Selected edge]

Bevel applied
[image: Bevel applied]

Here's my file if it's helpful: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3TF2HeeQRyWWkpVeVV5Vmc3T28/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

Aand I found the answer by looking up a separate question I had (why were my planes different colors):

The normals weren't consistent, so I guess it was trying to bevel on the reverse side. I selected the whole model and used Make Normals Consistent, and then beveling works fine.